# How to use overflow-y: auto on vertical flex-item?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w9ryv2Ln/1/).
Here is the **HTML**

```
<div class="overflow">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="header">
      This is green header
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      this is a lot of content<br> this is a lot of content<br> this is a lot of content<br> this is a lot of content<br> this is a lot of content<br> this is a lot of content<br>
      <button>
      add more
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and **CSS**

```
.overflow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
}
.block {
  width: 100px;
  background: white;
  max-width: calc(100% - 30px);
  max-height: calc(100% - 30px);
}
.header {
  background: green;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.content {
  min-height: 0;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

The problem is that if content is long enough to go outside of modal it doesnt add scrollbar but instead overflows `.content` div.

I tried using `min-height:0;`, but it did not help.

Comment: refer to my answer @Karlis

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('button').click(function(){
   $('.content').append('some more content<br>');
  });
});
```

```css
.overflow{
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    }
    .block{
     width: 100px;
     background: white;
     max-width: calc(100% - 30px);
 
    }
    .header{
     background: green;
     flex: 0 0 auto;
    }
    .content{
     float:  left;
     clear: left;
     overflow-y: auto;
     max-height: 350px;
   
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overflow">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="header">
      This is green header
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      this is a lot of content<br> this is a lot of content<br> this is a lot of content<br> this is a lot of content<br> 
      <button>
      add more
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

after some time i able to figure out this try this give max height to content as i gave here. hope it will help . try this and let me know

it will become scrolabe after reaching max height 350px you can set it on your own

Comment: Sorry, I just updated the code and jsfiddle in question. I want to take full use of flex-shrink and flex-grow. Header shoud always be fixed height, but content should adjust to amout of content - if there is just few lines it should grow to that but if it start overflowing it should add scrollbar

Comment: i figure out this wat u want exactly try this out @KārlisJanisels

Comment: @KārlisJanisels check this now

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.overflow{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
}
.block{
  width: 100px;
  background: white;
  max-width: calc(100% - 30px);
  max-height: calc(100% - 30px);
}
.header{
  background: green;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.content{
  min-height: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  text-overflow: clip;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: #fff;
}
```

live demo - https://jsfiddle.net/grinmax_/w9ryv2Ln/2/

Comment: Nah - I want the .content to scroll and header to be visible all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all that parcitipated in this problem, that helped me to find the error. I had forgot to add `display: flex; flex-direction: column` to `.block`.

Here is working example:

```
.overflow{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
}
.block{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100px;
  background: white;
  max-width: calc(100% - 30px);
  max-height: calc(100% - 30px);
}
.header{
  background: green;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 50px;
}
.content{
  //min-height: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  text-overflow: clip;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Comment: try out my answer @Karlis

Comment: This exactly answer I was going to write, when I saw that another fiddle. anyways I'll retract my answer, as it's not working for you.